# Looking for a Buddhist Monastery in UK, Ireland, Scotland or Australia - All traditions are welcome

Tags: monk, monastery

I have a friend from Sri Lanka who is a Theravada Buddhist monk. He is 36 (soon 37) years old and have been a monk for 19 years.

He resides in SL and has just finished an english language course and have asked me if I could help find a Buddhist monastery, where he could stay for 2-3 years. His goal is to practice and improve his language skills to eventually be able to give a full Dhamma talk in english.

It must a non-Sri Lankan monastery. Bhante would like to work with all Buddhist traditions. If you want to know more about him he has a [*FB profile.*](https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100008188150491) He has also written a short description of himself (this description is part of an email that Bhante himself has sent to monasteries - I have taken the self-description-part and put here):

> "Dear Venerable sir/madam
>
> My name is Venerable Buttala Samithawansha and I am 36 years old. I currently reside in a monastery in Colombo Sri Lanka. I am a fully ordained Buddhist monk.
>
> I grew up as a poor farmer's son and was not able to get my formal education particularly English, however I managed to join the British Council where I completed pre intermediate levels 1, 2 and 3, intermediate levels 1, 2 and 3 and upper intermediate levels 1 and 2.
>
> I stopped school at 17 years old and was ordained at 18 years old.
>
> I would be very grateful if you know of any scholarships or funding to facilitate people who are in my situation.I am keen to improve my English skills under guidance on the native English speakers. I would like to share Buddhist teachings in English language in the future.
>
> My most humble gratitude .
>
> Yours faithfully,
> Reverend Samithawansha"

Does anyone know of a Buddhist monastery, where that would be possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Forest Sangha [United Kingdom branches](https://forestsangha.org/community/monasteries/continents/countries/united-kingdom) - Amaravati, Cittaviveka, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Will look further into it.